# How to force a merge join?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have this query in my postgresql db

```
UPDATE main_table m 
SET new_prod=false 
FROM reseller_product p
WHERE p.distributor_id=896 
AND p.sku = m.sku 
AND p.reseller_id=8;
```

And it takes too long to execute. I have indexes on sku column in both tables. After using EXPLAIN command I saw that the planer used Hash Join. It seems to me that Merge Join would be faster here. Am I wrong ? Or maybe the planer used Merge Join because query has filters like "p.distributor_id=896"?

PS sku type is character varying(50)

```
"Update  (cost=80414.35..228437.71 rows=848460 width=212) (actual time=1582872.917..1582872.917 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash Join  (cost=80414.35..228437.71 rows=848460 width=212) (actual time=6906.044..23677.829 rows=706328 loops=1)"
"        Hash Cond: ((p.sku)::text = (m.sku)::text)"
"        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..96319.53 rows=1067877 width=20) (actual time=0.909..7426.880 rows=808287 loops=1)"
"              ->  Index Scan using res_prod_reseller_id on reseller_product p  (cost=0.00..8.74 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.729..0.729 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: (reseller_id = 8)"
"                    Filter: (distributor_id = 896)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on reseller_product_8 p  (cost=0.00..96310.79 rows=1067876 width=20) (actual time=0.168..3850.121 rows=808287 loops=1)"
"                    Filter: ((distributor_id = 896) AND (reseller_id = 8))"
"        ->  Hash  (cost=45779.60..45779.60 rows=848460 width=202) (actual time=6897.658..6897.658 rows=709948 loops=1)"
"              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 256  Memory Usage: 417kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on main_table m  (cost=0.00..45779.60 rows=848460 width=202) (actual time=0.926..2770.997 rows=709948 loops=1)"
```

Comment: would be better if you post the `EXPLAIN` plan

Comment: http://explain.depesz.com/s/z1m here it is

Comment: Can you please post both table definitions too?

Answer (score 3):

Your plan mentions that you are updating close to a million rows, `selecting` the data takes **23 seconds**, while **`updating` and `selecting` them takes 26 minutes**. `updating` them is the main problem rather than the plan used for `selecting` it

A `MERGE JOIN` would be preferred when you are mainly **ordering your results**. In your case `HASH JOIN` seems to be the appropriate choice as why would the planner waste time in ordering the results when its not needed. You could still **force the planner** to use `MERGE JOIN` by issuing 'set enable_hashjoin = off', but its likely to make the query slower.

I would suspect any **triggers/indexes** on the table being updated `main_table` or `multi-column index's` that contain the `new_prod`. I'd suggest to **disable the trigger** and/or add the `indexes` once you are done updating your records. Your read/write speed could also depend on other factors considering your hardware to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Are `sku` columns in `main_table` and `reseller_product` the same type in both tables?

Does reseller_product have an index in this order?

```
CREATE INDEX I_reseller_product_1 ON reseller_product (distributor_id,reseller_id,sku);
```

Does main_table have an index in sku column?

```
CREATE INDEX I_main_table_1       ON main_table      (sku);
```

If all questions are yes, try this:

```
UPDATE main_table m 
SET    new_prod = false 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 
               FROM   reseller_product p
               WHERE  p.distributor_id = 896 
               AND    p.reseller_id    = 8
               AND    p.sku            = m.sku 
               );
```